# How to test react-router Links with Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-router, enzyme

I see quite a few similar questions to this, but all seem wildly outdated or incredibly convoluted.

I have a React component which contains a React Router `Link` component, like so:

```
export default class Home extends Component {                                      
  render() {                                                                       
    return (                                                                       
      <div className="Home">  
        <Link to="/mission">Begin</Link>                                           
      </div>                                              
    );                                                                             
  }                                                                                
}
```

Then, I am trying to test very simply that the `Home` component contains a `Link` component which has a `to=/mission` property, using Jest. So, as per the [Testing React Router docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/testing.md), I tried many variations of tests, but this code most succinctly demonstrates what I am trying to achieve (example uses [jest-enzyme](https://github.com/blainekasten/enzyme-matchers#tocontainreactreactinstanceobject) for brevity):

```
it('includes link to Mission scene', () => {                                       
  const home = shallow(<MemoryRouter><Home /></MemoryRouter>);                                                              
  expect(home).toContainReact(<Link to="/mission">Begin</Link>)                    
});
```

Obviously, that code has several issues, not the least of which is the error:

```
Warning: Failed context type: The context `router` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

But notice the key bits: I want to *shallow* render (if possible) the `Home` component in order to test that component in isolation. At the same time, I am trying to wrap that in a `MemoryRouter` or somehow get the context in place so that I can test the `Link` components.

Astute potential answerers will notice that this issue is actually going to prevent *all* isolated tests of that component (not just tests related to React Router), because I can't shallow render the component at all.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Enzyme's [`find`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html) method:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';

it('includes link to Mission scene', () => {                                       
  const wrapper = shallow(<MemoryRouter><Home /></MemoryRouter>);
  expect(wrapper.find(Link).props().to).toBe('/mission');
 });
```

Comment: I'll need to go back to this code to check this answer, but my gut says this won't work. I believe the error was raised during the shallow render, not during the expect.

Comment: This cannot even work from a theoretical standpoint simply because shallow renders the outmost component only (<MemoryRouter> in this case) and the <Link> component is never exposed to the .find() method. Either use mount() instead of shallow or something like .dive().

Comment: Im getting following error when I tried above answer: ReferenceError: MemoryRouter is not defined

Comment: what import am I missing?

Comment: ```import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';```

Answer (score 4):

This is an info from official docs:

> If you try to unit test one of your components that renders a `<Link>`
>   or a `<Route>`, etc. you’ll get some errors and warnings about context.
>   While you may be tempted to stub out the router context yourself, we
>   recommend you wrap your unit test in a `<StaticRouter>` or a
>   `<MemoryRouter>`.

This [link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/testing) might be useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

The below example uses [Full Rendering API (mount(...))](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html#full-rendering-api-mount) of `enzyme`. So that we can find the `a` tag rendered by the `Link` component easily.

Use `createMemoryHistory` of `history` package to create memory history, because test code doesn't run in the real browser environment. And, install spy on `history.push()` method. Because when the user clicks the `a` tag, it will call `history.push()` method. We can check and assert this method is called or not.

So the complete code is:

`Home.tsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Home">
        <Link to="/mission">Begin</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`Home.test.tsx`:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { createMemoryHistory, MemoryHistory } from 'history';
import Home from './Home';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';

describe('45528156', () => {
  let memoryHistory: MemoryHistory;
  let pushSpy: jest.SpyInstance;
  beforeEach(() => {
    memoryHistory = createMemoryHistory();
    pushSpy = jest.spyOn(memoryHistory, 'push');
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    pushSpy.mockRestore();
  });
  test('should navigate to /mission route', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Router history={memoryHistory}>
        <Home />
      </Router>
    );
    const link = wrapper.find('a');
    link.simulate('click', { button: 0 });
    expect(pushSpy).toBeCalledWith('/mission');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  examples/45528156/Home.test.tsx (14.316 s)
  45528156
    ✓ should navigate to /mission route (41 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 Home.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.915 s
```

package versions:

```json
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

you can query by just inserting the name of a componet as string like any regular html element

```
it('includes link to Mission scene', function() {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MemoryRouter><Home /></MemoryRouter>);
    expect(wrapper.find('Link').prop('to')).to.be.equal('/mission');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

try `<MemoryRouter><Route><Home /></Route></MemoryRouter>`